# Android List-view with multiple progress-bar not working

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

I have a list of items where after clicking an item, a ProgressBar should be set a progress value that i want to set. I have done this, but it does not work (it does not show the progress value that is set).

```
HashMap<Integer,Boolean> states = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
    }


    progressBar = ((ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar));

    playButton  = ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause));

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(states.containsKey(position))
            {
                states.put(position, !states.get(position));
                playButton = ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause));
                playButton.setImageResource(states.get(position) ? R.drawable.button_pause : R.drawable.button_play);

                // Here i set the tag that the row of listview is clicked
                progressBar.setTag(position);

            }
            else
            {
                states.put(position, true);
                playButton = ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause));
                playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);

                // Here i set the tag that the row of listview is clicked
                progressBar.setTag(position);
            }



            // Here i want to get the clicked progressBar using the tag we set above
            progressBar.setProgress(100); // Does not work.... no effect on progressBar


            }
        }
    return view;
}
```

I have tried these, but no lock. I think, the problem is that if i use view, i get null pointer exception. Maybe it is because, i am trying to access the view at onClick(View view) of playButton. I do not know how to fix it, any help would be appreciated.

```
progressBar = ((ProgressBar) view.getTag());
progressBar = ((ProgressBar) convertView.getTag());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the OnClickListener is a callback which is not executed as part of the getView method, and you are saving the reference to your ProgressBar in an attribute of the enclosing class which is in fact being overwritten for every row in your list, effectively keeping only the last ProgressBar referenced. So every time you click on ANY of the rows you are actually updating the last ProgressBar rendered.

The solution would be to keep the reference to your progress bar in a final variable as part of the enclosing getView method context.

```
HashMap<Integer,Boolean> states = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
    }


    final ProgressBar progressBar = ((ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar));

    final ImageButton playButton  = ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause));

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(states.containsKey(position))
            {
                states.put(position, !states.get(position));
                playButton.setImageResource(states.get(position) ? R.drawable.button_pause : R.drawable.button_play);

                // Here i set the tag that the row of listview is clicked
                progressBar.setTag(position);

            }
            else
            {
                states.put(position, true);
                playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);

                // Here i set the tag that the row of listview is clicked
                progressBar.setTag(position);
            }



            // Here i want to get the clicked progressBar using the tag we set above
            progressBar.setProgress(100); // Does not work.... no effect on progressBar


            }
        }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: but, i get an error message for the imageButtons inside of onClick, it says: Cannot assign a value to final variable 'playButton'

Comment: thanks it seems to be working. However, i just realized that i have another problem about recycling. So, if i scroll down and up, the prograssbar's value is gone. How to fix that?

Comment: You will need to keep those values in some other place. You can for a example have a List with as many objects as rows in your list. There you can store Integers or a your own class object if you need more than one value. Then in your getView method you can use the position parameter as index for the list, and set the progress bar value. You will have also to update the list with the current progress bar value in the OnClickListener.

Comment: I actually did similar things for storing the playButtons, it was kind a easy because the image can be either play or pause state.But for this time i guess i should store the progress state and position of the progress bar item, right? and update accordingly

Comment: Yes, and instead of a hash map, you could use a simple array list, it's cheaper and easier to read. Try to initialize the list with the size of the list view items. I think you got the point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62087/discussion-between-leandro-glossman-and-co-koder).

Comment: Could you please provide some codes for doing this? Mine did not work out.

Comment: should i use getLayoutParams().width for each progressBar? I am confused, any help would be appreciated.